# For not acting the same with variable that has predefined value

Tags: c

Why is there an error in these two codes which should be the same?

This one works:

```
    int N=4;
    int M[N][N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {

            scanf("%d", &M[i][j]);

        }

    }
```

This one only reads one line:

```
    int i=0,j=0,N=4;
    int M[N][N];

    for(i; i < N; i++) {

        for (j; j < N; j++) {

            scanf("%d", &M[i][j]);

        }

    }
```

But if you add space in front of %d in scanf function it will read two rows.

Comment: `int i=0,j=0;N=4;`...you sure about the first `;`?

Comment: Sorry, copied the code wrong, fixed it now. Still, that is not the problem.

Comment: Never say you have "an" error, and leaving all of us in suspense on what error it could possibly be.

Comment: Right, I missed that one in my description. The program should have scanned 4 rows but it gave me only one to enter, or two if I put the space after %d in the scanf function for the second case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not re-initializing `j` to zero on each iteration, you need:

```
int i=0,j=0,N=4;
int M[N][N];

for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &M[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0,j=0,N=4;
int M[N][N];

//for(i; i < N; i++) {
    //for (j; j < N; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &M[i][j]); // i = 0; j = 0
    //}
//}


        j++;
        scanf("%d", &M[i][j]); // i = 0; j = 1
        j++;
        scanf("%d", &M[i][j]); // i = 0; j = 2
        j++;
        scanf("%d", &M[i][j]); // i = 0; j = 3
        i++;
        scanf("%d", &M[i][j]); // i = 1; j = 3
        i++;
        scanf("%d", &M[i][j]); // i = 2; j = 3
```

Comment: The first one solution was better because it uses for loop, this one doesn't read all the elements.